# Why does my ideal gas law and first law of thermodynamics not give me the same answer?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is it that sometimes, when I use pV=nRT, it does not give me the same answer as if I were to use Increase in U = WD + Q?

Comment: what 2 methods in part iii? I don't see a mention of 2 methods.

Comment: as in, if i use pv=nrt to solve, the ans i get is not the same as just looking at the work done. The one that i wrote down is pv=nrt method. The correct method is just to look at workdone

Comment: I still can't connect what you're saying with the picture. If you use pv=nrt to solve for what?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The gas is contained in an insulated cylinder. No heat enters or escapes this gas during the compression. Use the first law.

Comment: yeah i know to use the first law but why does pv=nrt not work

Comment: Why did you assume that the change in internal energy is 3*(NkT/2)? The factor of 3 is the number of degrees of freedom of the gas molecule - you're assuming that the gas is monoatomic. Why not 5 (diatomic)?  Since your process is adiabatic, try using the expression for adiabatic compression and find what kind of gas you are dealing with.

Comment: but even if i were to consider it as a diatomic molecule with 5/2, it still wouldnt yield the 91?

Comment: You're right. I suspect that your instructor did not calculate the actual work done on the gas. The question must have been just to illustrate the first law. You can try calculating the work done and "predicting" what kind of ideal gas it is.